# How marshalling return array of string on C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pinvoke, marshalling

I have below function on C++ (header)

```
string               __declspec(dllexport) *GetReaders(int& readerCount);
```

I wrote below method on C# for invoking

```
[DllImport("ABC.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto )]
        extern static string[] GetReaders(out IntPtr readercount);
```

But after run I can got readercount but the app got below error:

Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.

What is wrong?

I did it by java and work perfectly. But I have problem with .Net.

Comment: Marshalling is almost never trivial but marshalling strings is always guaranteed to be complicated. Is that a std::string array that you're returning from your method? How's that allocated?

Comment: 99% chance you have a memory leak

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to call that method with p/invoke. That's because you cannot marshal C++ classes using p/invoke. And `string` is, presumably, `std::string`.

You'll need to either use a C++/CLI wrapper, or re-design the C++ interface to be p/invoke friendly.